# Adicionar país ao Distance Matrix API

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou usando uma função para retornar do google matrix api, a distância entre duas cidades.

O problema é que quando as cidades tem nomes parecidos às de cidades Norte Americanas, o calculo da distancia dá erro.

Será que existe uma forma de informar à API que o país é o Brasil?

Eis a função:

```
  private function calculaDistancia () {

    $this->destino =  str_replace(" ","%20",$this->phpUtil->limpaCaracters($this->destino));

    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?Key=".$this->key."&origins=''".$this->origem."''|&destinations=''".$this->destino."''|&mode=''".$this->mode."''|&language=''".$this->language."''|&sensor=false
";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);     

    $freteXML = simplexml_load_string($data);
    $distancia = $freteXML->row->element->distance->value;

    return $distancia;

  }
```

eis a tentativa com a cidade Califórnia-PR

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=%27%27Muriae%27%27|&destinations=%27%27Calif%C3%B3rnia%27%27|&mode=%27%27CAR%27%27|&language=%27%27pt-br%27%27|&sensor=false

Obs.: Já tentei

region=br
pais=br

Nada dá certo.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que consegui.

Basta adicionar à cidade, seu estado.

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?Key=".$this->key."&origins=".$this->origem."-".$this->estadoOrigem."&destinations=".$this->destino."-".$this->estadoDestino."&mode=".$this->mode."&language=".$this->language."&sensor=false";
```